# How many crew members that Straw Hat should be?

Tags: one-piece

In very first of episode, Luffy said that 10 peoples are enough for his crew.
But I'm little curious, by 10 he mean, is 10 including himself or 10 other peoples on the ship plus Luffy?

I've read somewhere (I can't remember where I read, or even this is true or not) that Oda have stated the next crew is some kind "old enemy" of Luffy.
I don't think that Jinbei is the person that Oda said because he is not an enemy for Luffy at all (Once again I don't even know that Oda really said that old enemy thing).

So, I just want to know if Oda really said something about that old enemy of Luffy, and if so did Oda also stated about Straw Hat crew members are 10 including Luffy or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the initial quote was "about 10 people" so there is no hard and fast rule regarding the final size of Straw Hat Crew. 
I'd like the theory of 4 more people joining. 4 (Zoro, Usopp, Sanji, Nami joined in East Blue), + 4 (Chopper, Franky, Robin and Brook) in the first half of grand line

Among the next 4 I am thinking Jinbei is a given. That makes 10 but I'd like to think some other allies such as Caesar, Vegapunk etc. may also join. There is this really vast theory about the following members joining which draws parallels between the previous joinees and the future recruits

> Jinbei, Smoker, Unknown Warrior probably from Elbaf and Tashigi. I liked it especially since it filled the "old enemy Smoker" and another female recruit as well as a fishman. I also agree with the theory that Luffy's garp is Coby.

About Oda's quote, Unconfirmed rumours are floating around for ages. Next recruit is an old enemy, next recruit would be a female (Cue why people wanted Monet with Logia powers or Baby5) etc. etc.

http://www.marineford.com/Thread-One-Piece-Eiichiro-Oda-Interviews-Statements
This is a compendium of Oda's interviews that I find is well researched.

Answer (score -1):

Like already stated the quote was "About 10 People" keep in mind the series has changed multiple times. Oda originally planned for One Piece to be around 5-6 Years and now its past its 20th Anniversary and Oda already stated in an interview they are planning for the 30th. We also been told that the Series was mostly complete which gives us the impression the show may end with its 30th.

Alot of people stick with the crew of 10, they use Blackbeard as the reason saying there gonna fight at the end. Problem is if you count Blackbeard they are 11 and hes been openly seeking new members as seen with Kuzan.

The most popular theory is that they will end up being a crew of 13. with 4 members joining every milestone of the adventure.

Luffy

Starts in EAST BLUE

Zoro

Nami

Usopp

Sanji

Make it in the GRAND LINE

Chopper

Robin

Franky

Brook

Headed into the NEW WORLD

Jinbei

???

???

???

Many comparisons have been drawn.

Zoro was first seen chained to a post, Chopper was first seen chained to a sled, and Jinbei was first seen chained in jail.

Nami was a traitor working for Arlong one of East Blue's Big Three, Robin was a traitor working for Crocodile one of the Seven Warlords. (Because of this people think Pudding) She was also an traitor who works for Big Mom one of the Four emperors.

Usopp is tech based he came with the ship Going Merry, Franky is also tech based and brought along the ship All Sunny. Although we dont think the main ship will be replaced we assume the pattern will continue.

Finally Sanji and Brook are speedsters, in suits that are known perverts. We can assume the following.

My personal favorite is the Alphabet Theory and ill also mention the Country Theory due to its popularity due to Oda practically confirming it to some degree.

AB - Brook - Austria

CD - Chopper - Canada

EF - Franky - America

GH -

IJ - Jinbei - China

KL -Luffy - Brazil

MN - Nami - Sweden

OP - (Pudding?) - India

QR - Robin - Russia

ST - Sanji - France

UV - Usopp - Africa

WX -

YZ - Zoro - Japan

With the Country Theory that leaves Germany and England

Comment: Why Germany and England? Also I'm pretty sure Brook is Austria (specifically due to the musical history of Vienna).  Oh, and fan theories don't belong on this site so do not be surprised if someone (else) removes this answer.

Comment: Pudding aint Indian..